# I'm attaching an image to the cursor on mousemove. It works until I scroll, which detaches the image, moving it up on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Solution:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    var img = $(singleCardSearchElementIds.HoverImageClassName);
    var windowScrollY = window.scrollY;
    img.css({ 'top': windowScrollY + e.clientY, 'left': e.clientX + 20 });
});
```

---

This is what my main content looks like:

```
<main class="w-100 main-container">
    <div id="contentContainer" class="mw8 center content-container">
        <div id="cardContainer" class="flex flex-wrap">

        </div>
        <div id="tableContainer" class="mv2 dn">
            <img class="hover-card hover-card-loading dn" alt="" src="" />

            <table id="cardTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>CardId</th>
                        <th>Set</th>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Rarity</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                        <th>ImageUrl</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

By default, the image is hidden with the `dn` class. In JS, I remove this and set the source of the image when a row is hovered on. I'm using the page `mousemove` event to attach the image to the cursor:

```
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    var img = $(singleCardSearchElementIds.HoverImageClassName);
    img.css({ 'top': e.clientY - 110, 'left': e.clientX + 20 });
});
```

It works mostly fine when there are only a few rows:

[image]

But if there are a bunch of rows and I need to scroll, the image moves up the further I move the cursor down:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: What happens if you add the viewport's scroll Y to the top of the image's top css property. Since scroll Y starts out as 0 you get the desired behavior, but once that increments, you don't.

Comment: @GetSet You're a genius. I grabbed the window scrollY and added it to the cursor clientY and set that to the images Top property and it worked perfectly. Please submit an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey glad it worked. I will add an answer now. Hopefully it suffices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuation from comments, *What happens if you add the viewport's scroll Y to the top of the image's top css property. Since scroll Y starts out as 0 you get the desired behavior, but once that increments, you don't.*

```js
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    var img = $(singleCardSearchElementIds.HoverImageClassName);
    var topY = $(window).scrollTop();
    img.css({ 'top': topY + (e.clientY - 110), 'left': e.clientX + 20 });
});
```